# Error when filering on rowSums using dplyr

Tags: r, filter, dplyr, rowsum

I have the following df where df <- data.frame(V1=c(0,0,1),V2=c(0,0,2),V3=c(-2,0,2))

If I do **filter(df,rowSums!=0)** I get the following error:
Error in filter_impl(.data, quo) : 
  Evaluation error: comparison (6) is possible only for atomic and list types.

Does anybody know why is that?
Thanks for your help

PS: Plain **rowSums(df)!=0** works just fine and gives me the expected *logical*

Comment: 1. Your are trying to compare a function, `rowSums()`, to a numeric, `0`.  As the error message says, comparison is only possible for atomic and list types.

2. The `dplyr::filter` function is designed to take _column names_ as the 2nd argument.

Comment: Thanks Curt. Yes, I thought about that and I tried filter(df,everything(),rowSums!=0), but I get another error (Evaluation error: No tidyselect variables were registered). Is not there anyway to select all columns in cases like this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more `tidyverse` style approach to the problem is to make your data [tidy](http://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.pdf), i.e., with only one data value.

## Sample data

```
my_mat <- matrix(sample(c(1, 0), replace=T, 60), nrow=30) %>% as.data.frame
```

## Tidy data and form implicit row sums using `group_by`

```
my_mat %>% 
    mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
    gather(col, val, -row) %>%
    group_by(row) %>%
    filter(sum(val) == 0)
```

This tidy approach is not always as fast as base R, and it isn't always appropriate for all data types.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I got it.
filter(df,rowSums(df)!=0)

Not the most difficult one...
Thanks.